# How do I Include with AsQueryable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I want to include here. I want to type Include with GetQuery(). But include does not work.

```
public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> exp = null, params string[] includes)
        
        {
            var query = GetQuery(includes);
            return exp is null
                ? await query.ToListAsync()
                : await query.Where(exp).ToListAsync();
        }
```

GetQuery() Method:

```
private IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery(params string[] includes)
        {
            var query = _context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
            if (includes != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in includes)
                {
                    query.Include(item);
                }
            }
            return query;
        }
```

Comment: You probably want `query = query.Include(item);`

Comment: @Rafalon Thank you  so much. Inattention‍♂️.